# jQuery getJSON method with mixed http and https protocols

Tags: jquery, json

So right now I'm working on the FCC local weather app and I'm having some difficulty retrieving data from the weather API I'm using. I decided to use the Dark Sky API over the suggested Open Weather API just to change things up. This is what I have so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var lat, lon, city, api, temp, sum, windSpeed, percip;
  var apiKey = "##########################";

  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(data1) {

    lat = data1.lat;
    lon = data1.lon;
    city = data1.city;
    api = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/' + apiKey + '/' + lat + ',' + lon + '';

    $.getJSON(api, function(data2) {
      temp = data2.currently.temperature;
      sum = data2.currently.summary;
      windSpeed = data2.currently.windSpeed;
      percip = data2.currently.precipProbability;

      console.log(temp);

    });

  });

});
```

So right now I can get the ip-api to output to the console any of the variables that are assigned within that call. My issue is that I can't get the second call to the Dark Sky API to output anything to the console when I try to check for any of the variables value. That being said, the concatenated api variable will return the JSON data I need, but the method cant seem to retrieve it.

I tried to get some help on the FCC gitter chat and someone suggested not to mix http and https protocols, but switching both to the same protocol be it http or https wont return data at all.

I hope this is enough information.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more clearly what the issue is? A console log, or set this up as runnable code?

Comment: Don't see that you have an `apiKey` brought into the function. You only brought in `data1`.

Comment: @Esko I have the apiKey defined as the unique api key I have just before my first .getJSON method, but I excluded it from my example code for privacy reasons.

Comment: @brianlmerritt At its core I need it to be runnable, but I wanted to test whether or not I could retrieve data from the api so thats why I have the console.log line in there.

Comment: @ChristianTodd - you still haven't explained your issue, nor shared the console log. What isn't working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the `callback` query.
In the `api` variable definition, add `?callback=?`

Try the following.
`api = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/' + apiKey + '/' + lat + ',' + lon + '?callback=?';`

**TEST**
Here is a test in JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Esko/hqnszd5t/

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. Can you explain exactly why I need the callback query in this situation?

Comment: @ChristianTodd - The callback parameter passes a function to be used as a callback. If used, an asynchronous HTTP call will be used and will not return the forecast object directly, instead it will be passed to the callback function. Make sure it can accept it.  Check out JSONP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP  Here is an example `$.ajax` with `jsonp` specified: https://jsfiddle.net/Esko/ceqryowh/. Here is Working with [JSONP | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) explaining how to work with `JSONP`.

Comment: @ChristianTodd - If your question has been answered then you would upvote my answer and select this as your questions answer so I get points/credit for it. Thank you

Comment: Sorry about that. I cant quite give you the upvote just yet as I'm still too new. :(